# Pattern Recognition Letters, Keywords do not show up

Tags: macros

I am editing an article for the journal "Pattern Recognition Letters" using the according [template](http://cdn.elsevier.com/promis_misc/PRLetters-28012014.zip). I have replaced the dummy words with my keywords, but the keywords still do not show up in the PDF file. Can someone help me to resolve this problem please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Looking at the compiled example "prletters-template-with-authorship.pdf" provided with the template, the default keyword do not show up either. So - are the keywords expected to show up somewhere at all (where?)?

Comment: The template I used downlaod from http://cdn.elsevier.com/promis_misc/PRLetters-28012014.zip, and the editor have returned my manuscript because there are no keywords in the    first page of article.

Comment: In the PRLetters template, there are code:     \begin{keyword}
\MSC 41A05\sep 41A10\sep 65D05\sep 65D17
\KWD Keyword1\sep Keyword2\sep Keyword3

%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
\end{keyword}, but after compiled, the keywords does not shown up in the PDF file.

Comment: Package `prletters` is buggy. This is not your fault and not ours. Please ask the journal to update their package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it depends on a faulty version of a specific journal package/class.

Comment: @egreg, wait a moment, what do you gain if you close the question. I am chatting with pattern recognition letter staff for this problem!

Comment: @BetterEnglish The problem is not solvable unless the package is fixed. So it's off topic for the site.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem during submission. It is because you are using the buggy latex style file (prletters.sty). You must contact Elsevier support team to send you the new one.

Comment: You may also reach Elsevier via chat on the below link:
http://service.elsevier.com/app/chat/chat_launch/supporthub/publishing